# How to keep track of unique ranges in a 2D list of ranges?

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I want to build a list of probability ranges for characters in a string, so I can do [Arithmetic Coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) on them. 
Here's an example of what I'm looking to accomplish (from the tutorial/overview [here](http://michael.dipperstein.com/arithmetic)):

```
a   30%     [0.00, 0.30)
b   15%     [0.30, 0.45)
c   25%     [0.45, 0.70)
d   10%     [0.70, 0.80)
e   20%     [0.80, 1.00)
```

Expressed Pythonically / in the way my implementation does, this would look like:

```
[(0.00, 0.30), (0.30, 0.45), (0.45, 0.70), (0.70, 0.80), (0.80, 1.00)]
```

With an associated list of characters which match up with that list.
The ranges must be unique, and they must not collide. (Note that the upper bound of each range is actually an infinitely long list of `9`'s, because a given range's upper bound itself is occupied by the next range in the list.)

Here's my current implementation:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 2

def _nodupsfreq(string):
    """list deduplicator"""
    l, res = [], []
    for ch in string:
        if ch not in l:
            l.append(ch)
            res.append(string.count(ch))
    return l, res

def getprobs(string):
    """return a set of probability ranges for a string"""
    k, v = _nodupsfreq(string)
    rs = [(0, 0)]            # need a 0th element for first iteration (messy)
    x = []                   # construct the keys ensuring they match 
    for i in range(len(v)):
        y = 0 if i == 0 else i - 1 # this is the reason for the 0th element
        lower = rs[y][1]
        upper = Decimal(lower) + Decimal(v[i] / len(string))
        res = (lower, upper)
        rs.append(res)
        x.append(k[i])
    return rs[1:], x  # more messiness because of the first item

def probs_as_dict(string):
    """get a list of probability ranges as a dictionary"""
    l, k = getprobs(string)
    d = {}
    for i in range(len(k)):
        d[k[i]] = (float(l[i][0]), float(l[i][1]))
    return d

m = "BILL GATES"
__import__("pprint").pprint(probs_as_dict(m))
```

In *theory*, it does what it says on the tin, but in *practice* the only way it keeps the ranges "unique" is by basing the range in the next iteration on the upper bound of the range in the last iteration, which is demonstrably flimsy, shown by the results:

```
{
 ' ': (0.1, 0.2),
 'A': (0.2, 0.3),
 'B': (0.0, 0.1),  # occupied here!
 'E': (0.3, 0.4),  # occupied here!
 'G': (0.3, 0.4),  # junk
 'I': (0.0, 0.1),  # junk
 'L': (0.1, 0.3),
 'S': (0.5, 0.6),
 'T': (0.4, 0.5)
}
```

Overlapping ranges of the same and different lengths.

Surely, I could hack away even more at my implementation and get it to be better at eliminating dupe ranges, or I could select a better method for generating probability ranges from a string in the first place.

Is there a better way to express the probability of a given character in a string, a better way to ensure unique and noncolliding multidimensional elements in a collection, or how should I fix my code?

Comment: I really don't know how to tag this aside from what I have -- tag away with what you deem appropriate.

Comment: You could just save the length of each range, and that information is enough, because you know that the first range starts from `0.0` and that each other range starts where the previous ends. In this way, you cannot make two overlapping ranges, because range boundaries are implicit. This way, your first example becomes `[30.0, 15.0, 25.0, 10.0, 20.0]`. If you need the boundaries, you simply calculate them with a function, eliminating the risk of colliding ranges.

Comment: To calculate the length of each range, you simply divide the number of occurrences of the character by the total length of the string. These lengths are enough to describe your ranges as I already said in the previous comment.

Comment: @lodo wow, I hadn't even considered going simpler. post that as an answer and I'll accept it (unless someone has a better idea about probability retrieval in general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the length of the probability range of a character, you can simply divide the number of occurrences of the character by the total length of the string.

These range lengths that you obtain this way are enough to describe the ranges, because you know that the first range starts at `0.0`, and each successive range starts where the previous ends.

This way, there's no need to explicitly save the range boundaries, eliminating the possibility of collisions. If you need the boundaries in your computations, you can easily calculate them with a function.

So, in you example, you would just save an array of reals, like this:

```
[30.0, 15.0, 25.0, 10.0, 20.0]
```

Comment: Yes - saving an array of reals saves me having to make ranges right *now*, but I still have to generate nonoverlapping ranges *from* this list that I'd have anyways.

Comment: @cat Getting back your ranges from this list is easy and there's really no way you could do it wrong and have overlapping ranges.